# How to set up sublime-anaconda's python_interpreter for multiple platforms?

Tags: python, sublime-anaconda

I'm setting up [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) for Sublime Text 3.

In my Anaconda interpreter settings, I wish to specify one Python interpreter per operating system (Windows, macOS, Linux). Can this be done and if so, how?

From the [documentation](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/anaconda_settings/#python-interpreter-settings) on interpreter settings:

```
{
    "python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/pypy-c2.4"
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this isn't possible, as `"python_interpreter"` only takes a single string argument, not a dictionary with each key as an OS descriptor. You apparently just opened up an [issue](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/605) requesting this functionality, so it's up to DamnWidget to implement it. To speed that along, you could implement it yourself and submit a PR, but aside from that there's nothing else you can do at the moment.